# SQL INSERT INTO TABLE with dynamic and static column values

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Destination table called "codetypes":

| contractid | termid | code1 | code2 | code3 | createid | createdate | updateid | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| contractid1 | termid1 | static# | static# | A | staticname | getdate() | staticname | getdate () |
| contractid1 | termid1 | static# | static# | B | staticname | getdate() | staticname | getdate () |
| contractid2 | termid2 | static# | static# | A | staticname | getdate() | staticname | getdate () |
| contractid2 | termid2 | static# | static# | B | staticname | getdate() | staticname | getdate () |

Hello there!  Using SSMS 17.

Ok so what I'm struggling to efficiently achieve is a query that will insert rows into the table format above, but based on joined data to dynamically change the contractid and termid based on conditions from two other tables; as well as insert values from a known list of 20 options for code3.

The ContractID would be found from the "contract" table via a where condition based on the contract_name.  contract_name only exists in this "contract" table.

TermID would be found by a where condition based on the term_name and must be linked to the contractID above.  TermID and term_name only exists in the "term" table, linked on the contractID to "contract"

For just these two values the easy select would be:

```
select c.contractid, t.termid
from contract c
left join term t on t.contractid = c.contractid and t.term_name like 'term name%'
where c.contract_name like 'contract name%'
```

code1 and code2 are known values.  code3 has 20 values that each need to be inserted into this "codetypes" table, which are all numeric and alphabet characters (not *all* A-Z,1-0 but a smaller list of only 20 of those).  Restated, termid1 within in contractid1 need to have rows entered for all discrete 20 code3 values (A, B, C...Z, 1, 2...0), where the static fields are known but the contractid and termid are dynamically inserted based on the conditions described above.  The rest of the values are known static values or getdate() as well.

The 20 distinct codes exist in a 4th table we'll call "code3values", so I suppose they could be pulled from this table in the solution to cycle through code3 inputs.

What I would normally do is export the above select into Excel and then manually create an "insert into" line for every possibility, such as the very boring:

```
insert into codetypes values('contractid1','termid1','1','2','A','myname',getdate(),'myname',getdate())
insert into codetypes values('contractid1','termid1','1','2','B','myname',getdate(),'myname',getdate())
```

This time the data is too large and I want to learn a more efficient/creative way.

I think the below is a decent start but I still need a way to cycle through the 20 code3 value options.

```
insert into codetypes
(contractid, termid, code1, code2, code3, createid, createdate, updateid, lastupdate)

select c.contractid, t.termid, '1','2','A','name',getdate(),'name',getdate()
from term t
left join contract c on c.contractid = t.contractid
where t.term_name like 'term name%'
and c.contract_name like 'contract name%'
```

Comment: Move the t.term_name condition from WHERE to ON if you want true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't spend enough time myself before posting but here's the answer I came up with:

```
insert into codetypes
    (contractid, termid, code1, code2, code3, createid, createdate, updateid, lastupdate)
select
    c.contractid, t.termid, '1', '2', f.code3, 'name', getdate(), 'name', getdate()
from contract c
    left join term t on t.contractid = c.contractid
    join code3values f on f.code3 != ''
where c.contract_name like 'contract name%'
    and t.term_name like 'term name%'
```